# Dokku deployment issue unable to select build pack

Tags: docker, go, dokku

Hi I am trying to setup a digital ocean server along with dokku, whenever i push my local golang app to the dokku server, I'm receiving a the following error:

```
unable to select buildpack
```

along with the generic:

```
! [remote rejected] dev -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'dokku@....:tiny-web'
```

I have enabled dokku tracing and created a gist [here](https://gist.github.com/gdperkins/aed59257cccf5f7e56377b322911f416).

How can I fix this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to have the golang buildpack automatically detected, you'll need to follow the instructions in the [buildpack readme](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-go#example).

Comment: I see you work on the Dokku project, one more question, is there a way to run a custom build command before deployment? Because i want to run `godep restore` to pull in the vendors, im not a fan of committing all the vendors to source.

Comment: If you use the golang buildpack, you will need to commit the vendor directory, as that is what the [buildpack does](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-go/issues/33). Otherwise, you can use a Dockerfile for deploys.

Comment: Looking into Dockerfiles, they look like they will do the job, thanks for your help.